# One Angular Controller Karma-Jasmine test works, but not another one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

finally i got a karma test working for an angular controller. But if i try to execute nearly the same test with another controller, its not working with error message: `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Test2Controller' is not a function, got undefined`

the working test:

```
describe('TestController: - ', function() {
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
var scope, $controller, httpBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$controller_, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));
afterEach(function () {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
describe('version testing; -', function() {
    it("tests the version ", function() {

        httpBackend.whenGET('url').respond(200, {"meta":{"apiVersion":"0.1","code":200,"errors":null}});
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('TestController', { $scope: $scope });
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect($scope.version.meta.apiVersion).toEqual('0.1');
        expect($scope.version1).toEqual('1');
    })
})
});
```

everythings working fine here. But this one doesn't:

```
describe('Test2Controller: - ', function() {
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
var scope, $controller, httpBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$controller_, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));
afterEach(function () {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
describe('test 2 testing; -', function() {
    it("tests the test2 ", function() {

        httpBackend.whenGET('url').respond(200, {"meta":{"apiVersion":"0.1","code":200,"errors":null}});
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('Test2Controller', { $scope: $scope });
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect($scope.testVal).toEqual('Test Value');
    })
})
});
```

i also registered the test files in the karma config, but it's just working for the first one. Without the test environment (i mean my pure angular app) everything, every controller, is working fine. So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the error message is telling the truth: that there isn't a 'Test2Controller', at least in this situation. Perhaps it is named something else? Or perhaps it lives in a source file that you haven't included in karma.conf.js? Can't really tell for sure, but I'm guessing your test is fine, and the problem is karma failing to find your controller.

You might also want to try the debug button in the browser instance karma launches. This opens another page which you can inspect in the chrome dev tools or firebug or your fave JavaScript debugger. Keep diving in to see what karma has actually loaded, and you may spot the problem. Hope this helps.